# Android Theme.AppCompat theme

Tags: java, android, crash, android-alertdialog

My app crashes when I invoke alert dialogue within a list item. My app lists cars, every item has 2 buttons, each button calls alertdialog for yes/no answer. the app crashes with "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity." everytime I press the button. App code is as follows:

AndroidManifest:

```
<activity android:name=".SplashScreen" android:theme="@style/generalnotitle">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".CarActivity" android:theme="@style/generalnotitle"></activity>
</application>
```

Style:

```
<resources>
<style name="generalnotitle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:screenOrientation">portrait</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

CarActivity.java

```
public class CarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String[] car_tag, car_makemodel, car_owner_id;
TypedArray car_pic;
String[] aa_owner_id, aa_owner_name, aa_owner_tlf;
String tlf, name;

List<CarItem> carItems;
ListView mylistview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.e("list start", "list start" );
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    mylistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.LList);
    setUpListView();
}
public void setUpListView() {
    carItems = new ArrayList<CarItem>();
    // gets car info
    car_pic = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.a_carpic);
    car_tag = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.a_mat);
    car_makemodel = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.a_makemodel);
    car_owner_id = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.a_owner);
    //defines items
    for (int i = 0; i < car_tag.length; i++){
        CarItem item = new CarItem(car_pic.getResourceId(i, -1), car_tag[i], car_makemodel[i], car_owner_id[i]);
        Log.e("CarActivity", car_tag[i] );
        carItems.add(item);
    }
    //gets available owners
    aa_owner_id = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.a_id);
    aa_owner_name = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.a_name);
    aa_owner_tlf = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.a_tlf);
    //populates the list
    CarAdapter adapter = new CarAdapter(getApplicationContext(), carItems, aa_owner_id , aa_owner_name, aa_owner_tlf);
    mylistview.setAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

CarAdapter.java

```
public class CarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
List<CarItem> carItems;
String [] a_owner_id, a_owner_names, a_owner_tlf;
String name, tlf, owner_id;


CarAdapter(Context context, List<CarItem> carItems, String [] a_owner_id, String [] a_owner_names, String [] a_owner_tlf){
    this.context = context;
    this.carItems = carItems;
    this.a_owner_id = a_owner_id;
    this.a_owner_names = a_owner_names;
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_car,null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.car_pic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.car_pic);
        holder.tag = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tag);
        holder.makemodel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.make_model);
        holder.owner = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.owner);
        holder.blck = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.block);
        holder.mov = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.move);

        CarItem row_pos = carItems.get(position);

        holder.car_pic.setImageResource(row_pos.getCar_pic());
        holder.tag.setText(row_pos.getTag());
        holder.makemodel.setText(row_pos.getMakemodel());
        owner_id = row_pos.getOwner();
        getOwner(owner_id);
        holder.owner.setText(name);
        holder.blck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBlockClick();
            }
        });

        holder.mov.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("CarAdapter move click", owner_id );
            }
        });

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    return convertView;
}

private void onBlockClick() {
    Log.e("CarActivity", "CLICK block button" );
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDlg.setMessage("Do you wish to inform " + name + "?");
    alertDlg.setCancelable(false);
    alertDlg.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //Get owner phone number
            getNumber(owner_id);
            Log.e("CarActivity YES DIALOG", tlf );
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Afasta-me o teu cangalho...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    alertDlg.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Log.e("CarActivity", "CLICK NO DIALOG" );
        }
    });
    alertDlg.create().show();
}
}
```

SOLUTION: when I set adapter, i was sending "getApplicationContext()" but instead i sent "this" and this way i could send the context to the adapter.

CarActivity.java:

before:

```
CarAdapter adapter = new CarAdapter(getApplicationContext(), carItems, aa_owner_id , aa_owner_name, aa_owner_tlf);
```

after:

```
CarAdapter adapter = new CarAdapter(this, carItems, aa_owner_id , aa_owner_name, aa_owner_tlf);
```

Comment: Don't use `getApplicationContext()` for anything UI related, such as when making your `CarAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the constructor that takes the dialog's theme as well?

Try this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.generalnotitle);
```

Then put the rest of the relevant code for the builder.

Note, the theme should point to a dialog theme (Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert). Check out this post for more details.

http://www.materialdoc.com/alerts/

Comment: Tried this but got a "Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application" error. From CarActivity.java I send the getApplicationContext() as context in CarAdapter.java. Supposedly it should work. I tried the ....light.dialog.alert but still same error.

Answer (score 0):

There are two `AlertDialog` classes: the regular `android.app.AlertDialog`, and the support/appcompat version `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`. I can't tell which one you are importing, but the latter one requires you to be using an appcompat theme for the given `Context`, which should not be a problem if you are already using the AppCompat library and your activities extend from `AppCompatActivity`. (If you aren't using AppCompat, then you should make sure you are using the regular `AlertDialog`.)

Comment: I am using android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog, I tried the regular android.app.AlertDialog and got "Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application" error. From CarActivity.java I send the getApplicationContext() as context in CarAdapter.java. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: @RobertoDzija Use the Activity for the Context argument. The Application context does not have a theme.

Comment: SOLUTION: when I set adapter, i was sending "getApplicationContext()" but instead i sent "this" and this way i could send the context to the adapter.    CarAdapter adapter = new CarAdapter(this, carItems, aa_owner_id , aa_owner_name, aa_owner_tlf);